# How to use <unistd.h> library in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, unix

I am faced with a OS experiment to develop a Unix shell. In order to create a new process, I have to use the `fork()` function. However, the `fork()` function is defined in `<unistd.h>`, and I can not use it in Microsoft Visual Studio. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: What OS are you targetting? Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, it probably means you are targetting Windows...? `fork()` is not part of Windows API, you must then find another way to create a new process:

- Directly use Windows API: [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Use a cross-platform library (that will call`CreateProcess` on Windows and probably `fork` on Linux. Have a look at [Boost.Process](https://github.com/BorisSchaeling/boost-process) for instance (but there's probably others, like Qt's [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)

I would personnaly recommand the second approach (I use [Boost.Process](https://github.com/BorisSchaeling/boost-process)).

Answer (score 4):

`io.h` is the Visual Studio equivalent of `unistd.h`.